# Is it correct to say "he stretched his lip corner up"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

How to express and action of a person in which he/she tries to move 1 corner of his/her upper lip up high. It could be a smile that you disrespect someone or you give some negative attitude to someone or something. Or you do it when you feel bad about your life, for example, you lost your job or got a divorce.

[image]

[image]

Is it correct to say "**he stretched his lip corner up**"?

Answer (score 1):

Both of your images show examples of [**a grimace**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grimace#English):

> A contorted facial expression, often expressing contempt or pain.

The noun is **to grimace**:

> To make grimaces; to distort one's face; to make faces.

Grimacing indicates pain or distress, whether one's own or in sympathy with another's. It is usually made by stretching the entire side of one's mouth. If instead you want to indicate **disgust** you can use the phrase [**curl one's lip [in disgust]**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/curl+one%27s+lip), as you discovered. This action generally uses only part of one lip, rather than the whole mouth.

[image: A woman sneering]
[image: A man sneering]
<sup>Sources: [Kaitlyn on Pinterest](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/472385448390490699/), [Micro Expressions Training Videos](https://microexpressionstrainingvideos.com/micro-expressions-book-preview/)</sup>

This is very similar to [**a sneer**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sneer), with the difference that "sneer" has the connotation of *contempt* or *scorn* while "curl one's lip" has the connotation of *disgust*.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curl%20one%27s%20lip

I found this: "**curl his lip in disgust**"

Is that correct tooo?

"grimace" does not sound friendly in everyday conversation

Comment: @Tom, IMO your images show grimaces; curling one's lip is slightly different. See my expanded answer.